# How do I add security requirements to the password of my Django custom user model?

Tags: python, django

I'd like to start saying that I'm a beginner to Django, and I've been following a pretty great tutorial so far from Corey Schafer. In the project Corey uses the default Django User model, but I didn't want the users to log in with their username so I decided to override this as the Django docs say at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/.

I updated my registration forms with the new models and everything works fine. I can log in, log out and register properly, but I noticed that the password requirements for registration are gone. Previously Django would check if my password was too similar to the rest of my data, and had a minimum length requirement. I would like to know if there is a way to restore this feature.

Here is my code for users/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
from PIL import Image


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
   def create_user(self, email, name, password=None):
       """
       Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
       birth and password.
       """
       if not email:
           raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

       user = self.model(
           email=self.normalize_email(email),
           name=name,
       )

       user.set_password(password)
       user.save(using=self._db)
       return user

   def create_superuser(self, email, name, password=None):
       """
       Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
       birth and password.
       """
       user = self.create_user(
           email,
           password=password,
           name=name,
       )
       user.is_admin = True
       user.save(using=self._db)
       return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
   email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address',
                             max_length=255,
                             unique=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=63)
   is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   objects = UserManager()
   USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
   REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name

   def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
       "Does the user have a specific permission?"
       # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
       return True

   def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
       "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
       # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
       return True

   @property
   def is_staff(self):
       "Is the user a member of staff?"
       # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
       return self.is_admin


class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='profile_pics')
   description = models.TextField(max_length = 255, default = '', blank = True)

   def __str__(self):
       return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().save(*args, **kwargs)
       img = Image.open(self.image.path)
       if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
           outsize = 300, 300
           img.thumbnail(outsize)
           img.save(self.image.path)
```

This is my code in users/admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField

from .models import User, Profile


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'name')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'name', 'is_active', 'is_admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'name', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('name',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'name', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()


admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Profile)
```

And this is users/forms.py:

```
from .models import User
from .admin import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile


class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()


    class Meta:
        model = User 
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2'] 

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['name', 'email']

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image', 'description']
```

Comment: "Django would check if my password was too similar to the rest of my data" it's not clear what you mean by this sentence. Do you mean password confirmation check does not work?

Comment: I believe they're referring to `UserAttributeSimilarityValidator`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/passwords/#included-validators

Comment: Yes, I was referring to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change options of password in your settings.py  in variable AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/passwords/#password-validation

For exemple for changing minimal lenght:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'min_length': 8,
    }
},
```

]

Comment: Thank you, this has worked for me when creating users from admin site, but for some reason it does not work when using the registration forms. Do you know why would this be?